# Is it possible to center list on page programically on Reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm interested to center (dynamically) the list/table on page.

Eg I have table with unknown records count (only in runtime will know that)

So how to center it on the page?

Comment: Are you trying to center it vertically or horizontally?

Comment: What tool are you using to create your report?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself, but have you thought about setting the top position or margin based on an expresssion? Something like the following pseudo code

```
( < pageHeight> - (<numRows> * <rowhieght>) ) / 2
```